# Example Transforming A time series using the Backshift operator

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, seasonality, differential-equations

I am trying to understand the idea of **differencing** (using the **Backshift operator**): Let's look at this times series: $$X_t = at^2+bt+c+Y_{t-1}$$ with $Y_t$ being some (mean-zero) white noise process. How do I exactly the define the Backshift operator, and can I somehow transform this series into some stationary series?

By the **Backshift operator** $B$ I mean the solution to the equation: $$BX_t=X_{t-1}$$
The way I see it: the only way a transformation is stationary is if $B$ doesnt depend on $t$, but how is that possible?

Comment: You can decompose your time series in the sum of two. , The noise and the expression $a^2t+bt+c$, the last expression is the trend of your model.

Comment: Note that the part that defines the trend is not random, only the noise is random.

Answer (score 1):

The backshift operator is just that, an operator. It is not the solution to any equation. 
It is an operation defined on a time series, in the same way that we define the mean of a time series or the variance of a time series, and its definition is: $BX_t = X_{t-1}$

Applying it to your series:

$$X_t = at^2+bt+c+Y_{t-1}$$

We get:

$$BX_t = a(t-1)^2+b(t-1)+c+BY_{t-1}$$

$$= at^2 + (b- 2a)t+ a-b+c+Y_{t-2}$$

The best way to understand differencing is as a discrete equivalent to differentiating for continuous variables.

In the case of the example you give, the series has a quadratic trend, so you would have to difference it twice to make it stationary.